# Modify and build spark-mllib locally

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I', trying to build mllib spark module locally after editing code in one of classes.

I've read this solution:
[How to build Spark Mllib submodule individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391829/how-to-build-spark-mllib-submodule-individually)
But when I build the module using maven, the result `.jar` is like the version in repository and the class doesn't have my code.

I've modified `BisectingKmeans.scala` class, because one of the fixes done in one pull requesto of github https://github.com/apache/spark isn't in the last release jet.

The version I'm trying to build:

```
mllib 2.11
spark: 2.1.0
```

I need to change `BisectingKameans.scala` class from this:

```
  /**
   * Updates assignments.
   * @param assignments current assignments
   * @param divisibleIndices divisible cluster indices
   * @param newClusterCenters new cluster centers
   * @return new assignments
   */
  private def updateAssignments(
      assignments: RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)],
      divisibleIndices: Set[Long],
      newClusterCenters: Map[Long, VectorWithNorm]): RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)] = {
    assignments.map { case (index, v) =>
      if (divisibleIndices.contains(index)) {
        val children = Seq(leftChildIndex(index), rightChildIndex(index))
        val selected = children.minBy { child =>
          KMeans.fastSquaredDistance(newClusterCenters(child), v)
        }
        (selected, v)
      } else {
        (index, v)
      }
    }
  }
```

To this:

```
  /**
   * Updates assignments.
   * @param assignments current assignments
   * @param divisibleIndices divisible cluster indices
   * @param newClusterCenters new cluster centers
   * @return new assignments
   */
  private def updateAssignments(
      assignments: RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)],
      divisibleIndices: Set[Long],
      newClusterCenters: Map[Long, VectorWithNorm]): RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)] = {
    assignments.map { case (index, v) =>
      if (divisibleIndices.contains(index)) {
        val children = Seq(leftChildIndex(index), rightChildIndex(index))
        val newClusterChildren = children.filter(newClusterCenters.contains(_))
        if (newClusterChildren.nonEmpty) {
          val selected = newClusterChildren.minBy { child =>
            KMeans.fastSquaredDistance(newClusterCenters(child), v)
          }
          (selected, v)
        } else {
          (index, v)
        }
      } else {
        (index, v)
      }
    }
  }
```

And build.
But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another class that extends the class you want to modify:

```
class MyBisectingKmeans extends BisectingKMeans {
  override private def updateAssignments(
                                 assignments: RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)],
                                 divisibleIndices: Set[Long],
                                 newClusterCenters: Map[Long, VectorWithNorm]): RDD[(Long, VectorWithNorm)] = {
    assignments.map { case (index, v) =>
      if (divisibleIndices.contains(index)) {
        val children = Seq(leftChildIndex(index), rightChildIndex(index))
        val newClusterChildren = children.filter(newClusterCenters.contains(_))
        if (newClusterChildren.nonEmpty) {
          val selected = newClusterChildren.minBy { child =>
            KMeans.fastSquaredDistance(newClusterCenters(child), v)
          }
          (selected, v)
        } else {
          (index, v)
        }
      } else {
        (index, v)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some classes used in this method are private (for example, `VectorWithNorm`), so for accessing those in your local project you could create a package with the path `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering` and copy the code of that class in there, so your new BisectingKMeans can access it.

I've done it with other Spark MLlib classes, I haven't tried it out for this specific one, so I am not sure if there are some more specific details to take into account in this case (the private methods or classes needed should be duplicated locally, but for minor changes like this there shouldn't be that much code needed).

Doing it this way you don't need to rebuild Spark MLlib.